# Changes on NSCoding protocol

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding

I just came back on the development of a Swift application for iOs that I started back on August. It seems that a lot of changes happened. Now my NSCoding protocol is not valid anymore and I cannot find what's wrong. Actually I do but I don't know how to implement my old code with the new protocol. Here is my old `init(coder: NSCoder)` :

```
required init(coder: NSCoder!) {
    if (coder != nil) {
        //Variables initialization
    }
    else {
        //Defaults values
    }
    super.init()
}
```

Actually, I cannot use `NSCoder!` anymore so I cannot check if there is a coder so if I have to set default values or not. The question is : When coder is nil, what initializer is called ? Is it `init` or `init(coder: NSCoder!)` ? If it's the second one, how to do what I use to do (with the code above) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the updated protocol it is illegal for a Swift class implementing `NSCoding` to receive `nil` in `initWithCoder`. This should simplify your code since a `nil` coder is an exceptional case and the program should have taken an alternative path when it couldn't create the decoder.

If you really have two paths you can break your init into two methods:

```
override init() {
    //Variables initialization
    super.init()
}

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    //Defaults values
    super.init()
}
```

This does have implications for Objective-C code consuming this class since passing `nil` will crash the app. Swift code will be safe since it will generate a compilation error is you pass an optional.